# app which will record the ussd or sms

Tags: android, sim-toolkit

As we know that, when we use any menu in sim toolkit it send command to mobile network in ussd or sms format.
I need that sms or ussd to record and show it to me in android application.

I am calling the library service which i got in main activity like this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent srvIntent = new Intent(this, CDUSSDService.class);
    startService(srvIntent);


}   
}
```

USSD Service Class is like that:

```
    public class CDUSSDService extends Service{

    private String TAG = CDUSSDService.class.getSimpleName();
    private boolean mActive = true;//false  //we will only activate this "USSD listener" when we want it


    BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
        {
            if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_INSERT))
            {
                //activity wishes to listen to USSD returns, so activate this
                mActive = true;
                Log.d(TAG, "activate ussd listener");

                showtoast(""+"activate ussd listener");
            }
            else if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_DELETE))
            {
                mActive = false;
                Log.d(TAG, "deactivate ussd listener");
                showtoast(""+"DeActivate ussd listener");
            }
        }
    };

    private final IExtendedNetworkService.Stub mBinder = new IExtendedNetworkService.Stub () 
    {
        public void clearMmiString() throws RemoteException 
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "called clear");
            showtoast("called clear.");
        }

        public void setMmiString(String number) throws RemoteException 
        {
            Log.d (TAG, "setMmiString:" + number);
            showtoast("setMmiString:"+number);
        }

        public CharSequence getMmiRunningText() throws RemoteException
        {
            if(mActive == true)
            {
                return null;
            }

            return "USSD Running";
        }

        public CharSequence getUserMessage(CharSequence text)
                throws RemoteException {
            Log.d(TAG, "get user message " + text);
            showtoast("GET Usr Message:"+text);

            if(mActive == false){
                //listener is still inactive, so return whatever we got
                Log.d(TAG, "inactive " + text);
                showtoast("inactive:"+text);
                return text;
            }

            //listener is active, so broadcast data and suppress it from default behavior

            //build data to send with intent for activity, format URI as per RFC 2396
            Uri ussdDataUri = new Uri.Builder()
            .scheme(getBaseContext().getString(R.string.uri_scheme))
            .authority(getBaseContext().getString(R.string.uri_authority))
            .path(getBaseContext().getString(R.string.uri_path))
            .appendQueryParameter(getBaseContext().getString(R.string.uri_param_name), text.toString())
            .build();

            sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, ussdDataUri));

            mActive = false;
            return null;
        }
    };

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "called onbind");

        //the insert/delete intents will be fired by activity to activate/deactivate listener since service cannot be stopped
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_DELETE);
        filter.addDataScheme(getBaseContext().getString(R.string.uri_scheme));
        filter.addDataAuthority(getBaseContext().getString(R.string.uri_authority), null);
        filter.addDataPath(getBaseContext().getString(R.string.uri_path), PatternMatcher.PATTERN_LITERAL);
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);

        return mBinder;
    }   


    public void showtoast(String str)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    }
```

I have created MainActivity inside the UssdLibray structure is like that in the below picture:

[image]

Comment: i have started this service and i am not getting any SHOWTOAST() message when i send or receive message,I want to show the USSD/SMS in textview in my main activity please i am really stuck in this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this with the help of this library https://github.com/alaasalman/ussdinterceptor

Comment: Dear the code of this library is properly explained with comments each and every method, listeners etc are properly commented just read and get data from that intents and parameters

Comment: Dear if you have implement it properly then see your LogCat you will see all USSD etc

Comment: Dear in this class https://github.com/alaasalman/ussdinterceptor/blob/master/src/com/codedemigod/services/CDUSSDService.java
you can see Log.d() and comments . i think it will clear your concept about this library

Comment: please post your code. how you implement this library? have you start its service?

Comment: sir i am waiting for your help